# Toggle display on click jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an accordion that...

1. When clicked i want the next `dd` section to expand.
2. If another is clicked i want all the other open sections to close first
3. If an open title is clicked Id like to close...

I have the following example that I cant get working...

**jQuery**

```
$(".accordion > dt > a").click(function () {
    $(".accordion a").removeClass('active');
    if ($('.accordion > dd').next().is(':visible')) {
        $(this).removeClass('active');
        $('.accordion > dd').slideUp(200);
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $(this).parent().next().slideDown();
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/m0zehxpc/

Comment: Perhaps you can show a fiddle?

Comment: Add your `HTML` code

Comment: I think one of the problems is that you are not allowing the `else` condition to work. And also the last rule is your CSS looks faulty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed few things in your code and now it works like any other standard accordion.

**JS Code :**

```
 $(".accordion > dt > a").click(function () {
 var $this = $(this);
 var content = $this.parent().next();
 if (!$this.hasClass('active')) {
     $(".accordion a").removeClass('active');
     $('.accordion > dd').slideUp(200);
     $this.addClass('active');
     content.slideDown();
 } else {
     $this.removeClass('active');
     content.slideUp(200);
 }
});
```

**Live Demo @ JSfiddle:**

```
http://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/m0zehxpc/12/
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like **[this](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/m0zehxpc/6/)**

```
$(".accordion > dt > a").click(function () {
    $(".accordion a").removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $('.accordion > dd').not($(this)).slideUp(200);
    $(this).parent().next('dd').slideDown(200)
});
```

You can just ignore `.not` part in this

```
$('.accordion > dd').not($(this)).slideUp(200);
```

Comment: May i know the meaning of `$('.accordion > dd').not($(this)).slideUp(200);`

Comment: @papsk Except the clicked element's `dd` slide up all the other `dd` but that seemed irrelavant here as he has close everything first and then open the clicked one.

Comment: Thank you ji...but i can't understand this...initially all are closed only na...then why it is irrelevant

Comment: @papsk It will be useful when you open one `accordion` and when you click other you might need to close the opened one!

Comment: its getting closed na ji...When we do click on one accordion it is displaying,if we opened other one the previously opened is getting hide and current one is displaying na,then what's wrong :(

Comment: that's because of code in 3rd line ->`$('.accordion > dd').not($(this)).slideUp(200);` comment that line and then check

Comment: `not(":even")` does not consider the elements which are at even index when referred from their parent!!

Comment: ok ji....very perfect:) it follows the index....ok i confused simply with the count

Answer (score 0):

```
  $("dt").click(function () {     
  $('dd').slideUp();
  $(this).next('dd').slideDown();
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```js
$(".accordion > dt > a").click(function () {
     var $myDD = $(this).parent().next();
     $(".accordion a").removeClass('active');
     $(this).addClass('active');
     $('dd').slideUp();
     
     if ($myDD.is(':visible')) 
         $myDD.slideUp();
     else 
         $myDD.stop().slideDown();
 });
```

```css
.about-us .accordion {
    padding: 0 1.6em;
    max-width: 970px;
    margin: 0 auto 50px auto;
}
.about-us .accordion dt {
    margin: 0 0 5px 0;
}
.about-us .accordion dt a {
    background:#EDEFEF no-repeat scroll right 0px !important;
    color: #4e5663;
    display: block;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 16px;
}
.about-us .accordion dd {
    display: none;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: -7px 0 5px 0;
    border: 2px solid #00b0e4;
}
body.about-us .accordion a.active {
    background:#00B0E4 no-repeat scroll right -67px!important;
    color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="about-us">
    <dl class="accordion"> <dt>
            <a href="#title">Title</a>
        </dt>

        <dd style="">
            <p>lorem upsum dolor sit amet</p>
        </dd> <dt>
            <a href="#title">Title</a>
        </dt>

        <dd style="">
            <p>lorem upsum dolor sit amet</p>
        </dd> <dt>
            <a href="#title">Title</a>
        </dt>

        <dd style="">
            <p>lorem upsum dolor sit amet</p>
        </dd> <dt>
            <a href="#title">Title</a>
        </dt>

        <dd style="">
            <p>lorem upsum dolor sit amet</p>
        </dd> <dt>
            <a href="#title">Title</a>
        </dt>

        <dd style="">
            <p>lorem upsum dolor sit amet</p>
        </dd>
    </dl>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are much answers already.However you can try this code at thisfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/m0zehxpc/2/

```
var datapanel = $('.accordion > dd').hide(); 
$('.accordion > dt > a').click(function() {
 datapanel.slideUp(200);
 $(this).parent().next().slideDown();
 return false;
});
```